# DevArt MySQL components connecting to MySQL with Shared Memory protocol

Tags: mysql, .net, devart

Has anybody had success with connecting to MySQL using the Shared Memory protocol via the DevArt components? (in .NET)

If so, how did you do it, what is the connection string? And what other gotcha's are there?

Note I have the sever started fine with...

```
mysqld --skip-networking --shared_memory=1 --shared-memory-base-name='MyName'
```

and I can access it just fine with the MySQL.exe client via...

```
MySql --protocol=memory --shared-memory-base-name="MyName'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the DevArt connectors working :-( And also discovered that even if I did get it working I would then have a depencency on libmysql.dll (shared memory is not supported in DevArts "direct" mode)

So I tried the [MySQL connectors](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), the new ones are VASTLY better than the dodgy things they had a couple years ago, in fact DevArt components may lose a reason to exist soon I fear. They worked great in shared memory mode, without any depencency on libmysql.dll. The only thing I would say is that the connection string on connectionstrings.com is totally incorrect for the new connectors, it should be....

User Id=root;Connection Protocol=SharedMemory;Shared Memory Name="Fred Blogs"

Comment: you have saved my day with providing the option `Connection Protocol=SharedMemory` for connection string. I couldn't figure out why my application can't connect to the mysql server which is configured with options `skip-networking` and `shared-memory`. Thanks Tim !